# Angular - how do I listen to emits from on certain instances?

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular HTML fragment that displays a drop-down. This fragment has a controller that loads the drop-down from a webApi and keeps up with the selected value.

I add the drop-down fragment to my main page with ng-include.  I want my main controller to perform an action when the drop-down value changes.  For this, I use $emit in the drop-down controller and I listen for it using $on in the main controller.

My problem is that I have multiple instances of the drop-down fragment on my main page.  I only want the main to react to the change on one of them - not all of them.

The drop-down HTML is similar to this:

```
<div ng-controller="dropDownCtrl">
   ... the drop down ....
</div>
```

Here is the emit in the drop-down controller:

```
$scope.SetSelectedValue = function (newID) {
        $scope.$emit("NewValueSelected", newID);
    };
```

The main controller listens with this:

```
$scope.$on('NewValueSelected', function (event, newID) {
   //do something
})
```

And my main.html page uses this fragment multiple times:

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <span ng-include src="drop-down.html" />
  .....
  <span ng-include src="drop-down.html" />
  .....
  <span ng-include src="drop-down.html" />
</div>
```

I want to do something when the value in the first one changes.  If it's the second one I want to do something different.  And for the third one I want to do nothing at all.

I know some workarounds but I would like to know the best practice.

Comment: Have you tried the service approach?

Comment: Instead of using ng-include, you should make the dropDown a directive, taking an onSelect argument as an attribute (with '&' binding). The main controller would then be free to pass whatever expression to execute when the dropdown selection changes, and could of course pass a different argument to each dropDown. Just like the standard `select` directive takes an ng-change argument, allowing to do that.